# N2CMS Issues creating template first parts

Tags: n2cms, n2, dinamico

What is the proper way of adding template first part as shown here..https://n2cmsdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/524349

I have done the same thing in my mvc project and the part appear in the drag drop list with the name of "ContentPart". When I edit the part, an empty page shows up.

If I add more parts in /views/ContentParts/ folder, they don't show up in the drag drop list.

I have tried copying several parts from dinamico source but they don't appear in the list. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your view or model must define some editable fields. If you're defining the fields in your view (as in the Dinamico template pack) you can do this with the `Content.Define` function, i.e.

```
@model Dinamico.Models.ContentPart
@{ 
  Content.Define(a => /* add definitions here */);
}
```

If you're doing it from your model, you can decorate public properties with attributes like `[EditableText]` to make them show up in the edit form automatically.

There are many built-in editor types which are discussed in the documentation here: https://n2cmsdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/display/N2CMS/Built-in+Editor+Types